# Liferay lucene indexing of documents

Tags: java, lucene, liferay, liferay-6

Recently I implemented a custom portlet within some documents from an external repository are uploaded through a job to Liferay system (physical files and DB).

Can anyone explain to me what happens seamlessly and these files are indexed using Liferay's Lucene indexing mechanism?

For example is there an indexing job triggered after executing DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry(.,.,..) or DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.updateFileEntry(.,.,.,)

Comment: see https://www.liferay.com/en_GB/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/57921340